# Select first row of each conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i select the first row of each conversation of a specific user where the `to_id = 1`.

The big problem is when the first message exchanged does not have the `top_id = 1` ends up listing the next that have the `from_id = 1` and should not.

This is the link to SQLFIDDLE:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a772b/4

In the SQLFIDDLE is listing the `Test 1` and `Test 4` when should listing just the `Test 1`, because the conversation `Test 4` starts on `Test 3` where don't have the `to_id = 1`.

SQL

```
SELECT t1.*, m2.message, m2.from_id FROM
    (SELECT to_id,message, MIN(created_at) AS created_at FROM messages m
    WHERE to_id = 1
    GROUP BY to_id,message) AS t1
INNER JOIN messages m2 ON t1.created_at = m2.created_at
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Plainly, the destinario_id is NOT different from 1

Comment: @D-Shih i edited the post with more informations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `min` fucntion and subquery

```
select t1.*,m2.mensagem,m2.remetente_id  from
    (select destinatario_id ,min(created_at) as created_at from mensagens m
    where destinatario_id=1
    group by destinatario_id) as t1
inner join mensagens m2 t1.created_at =m2.created_at
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, in that case it works, but when you have a conversation where the destinatario_id = 1, it returns only one line

Comment: so remove the condition from where clause @DiegoVieira

Comment: @DiegoVieira i used where as you used thats why other wise according to your expectation hope it will fulfil your demand

Comment: it is necessary to have the where to bring only the messages that the user 1 received. I edited the post with one more example of how it would return more than one result

Comment: for 2nd example what will be your condition could share with me please

Comment: Where the the first row of every conversation has the destinatario_id = 1.

Comment: On this case the first message exchanged between the user 1 and 3 was the user 1 who received it, so it should be listed. In the first example it was user 1 that sent it, so it was not to be listed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177442/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-diego-vieira).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the earliest time for the conversations using:

```
select least(remetente_id, destinatario_id) as id1,
       greatest(remetente_id, destinatario_id) as id2,
       min(id) as min_id
from mensagens m
where 1 in (remetente_id, destinatario_id)
group by id1, id2;
```

(This assumes that `id` is ascending with the date time, which is reasonable.)

Then you can get the full rows using `join` or `in`:

```
select m.*
from mensagens m join
     (select least(remetente_id, destinatario_id) as id1,
             greatest(remetente_id, destinatario_id) as id2,
             min(id) as min_id
      from mensagens m1 
      where 1 in (remetente_id, destinatario_id)
      group by id1, id2
     ) mm
     on mm.min_id = m.id;
```

Comment: Returns the error:  In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'm1.remetente_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: I edited the post with updated informations and the SQLFIDDLE for you have a better understanding.

Comment: It is listing "test 3", but the conversation between the user 1 and 3 does not start with the user 1 receiving the message, so should only list "test 1". http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db7d60/1

Comment: The idea is list the first message of each conversation that the logged user has not started